# Width of a container not automatically adjusting based on content inside

Tags: html, css

I have a div inside which I have content. I gave width = auto and then gave max-width but the container is taking up a constant fixed no matter what the size of the content is:

```css
.adjustablebox {
  background: white;
  height: 50px;
  width: auto;
  overflow: hidden;
  padding: 8px;
  max-width: 350px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  position: relative;
  top: 0;
  left: 30%;
}

.body {
  background: black;
}
```

```html
<div class="body">
  <div class="adjustablebox">
    <span>Hello world</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Block-level elements (like `<div>` elements) take up as much width as they can by default. If you want them to take up only as much width as their contents, set them to `display: inline-block;`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

div is an block element. its default behaviour is covering full width so its doing that but as you have given property of max-width so its just expanding to that limit. in order to do your stuff you have to change its behaviour to

```
display: inline-block;
```

Answer (score 1):

the .adjustablebox div is block level, it takes the entire available width of the container.

If you want it to be auto width you can do

```
    .adjustablebox {
       display: inline-block;
}
```

or use flex box.

Answer (score 0):

instead of using `auto`, use `100%` and remove `max-width`.
Also you can remove both tag

```
.body {
      background: black;
    }

.adjustablebox {
      background: white;
      height: 50px;
      width: 100%;
      overflow: hidden;
      padding: 8px;
      border-radius: 5px;
      position: relative;
      top: 0;
      left: 30%;
    }
    

<div class="body"> 
<div class="adjustablebox">
    <span>Hello world</span>
    </div>
</div>
```

hope this will solve your problem.